# How do I turn off the “extension recommendations” notification?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Every time I open Visual Studio Code, I get a notification:

```
This workspace has extension recommendations.
```

[image: This workspace has extension recommenations.]

**How do I turn off extension recommendations?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> **How do I turn off extension recommendations?**

### I found 5 ways to turn off the recommended extensions notification in VS Code:

1. Click the "Don't show again" option under the gear icon menu the next time the extension recommendations notification pops up. This is an easy way to turn off recommended extensions user by user.
   [image: Gear icon in extension recommendations]

2. You can go to the Extensions menu to turn off recommended extensions

Click the Extensions icon on the left menu > ... > Views > Uncheck Recommended extensions

[image: 1. Extensions icon 2. Views 3. ... 4. Recommended extensions]

3. There is a `<repo name>/.vscode/extensions.json` with a list of recommendations. Mine looked like this:

   ```
   "recommendations": [
     <extension name>,
     <extension name>,
     ...
   ],
   ```

Remove any or all unwanted recommendations!

4. Another solution: Add one of the extensions in the recommended list to the unwanted list. For example,

   ```
    "unwantedRecommendations": ["<extension name>"]
   ```

5. On the left menu, go to Extensions (Ctrl+Shift+F) > Select a recommended extension > Ignore Recommendation. This allows you to remove recommendations one by one.

Comment: How do I do step #1 after I already frustratingly close the message box, and turn them all off? Step 4.5 Settings label is "Extensions: Ignore Recommendations" or "extensions.ignoreRecommendations" in the settings.json from Timo below.

Answer (score 19):

In the new update of VS Code.

Recommendations can be disabled in the view

- Open extension view from the side bar
- Click on the 3 dots in the right hand corner of the extension view
- Click on View

Enable or disable recommendations from there.

[image]

or if you don't want to see the recommendations at all then disable it in settings file

Open `settings.json` (Press `Ctrl + Shift + P` type settings.json)

- set `extensions.ignoreRecommendations` to `true`

Comment: `set extensions.showRecommendationsOnlyOnDemand to true` seems to do it, `extensions.ignoreRecommendations` does not help as seen [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/43221). However, the first seems to be deprecated in favor of second.